# deseo poder recuperar y actualizar los campos de _EnterpriseAttributes de un suscriptor en AMPSCRIPT, ya que no conozco mas lenguajes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, subscriber

(Title Translation via Google Translate: I want to be able to retrieve and update _EnterpriseAttributes fields from a subscriber)

deseo poder recuperar y actualizar los campos de _EnterpriseAttributes de un suscriptor, es decir los campos de usuario y sus atributos, los campos de _Subscribers los estoy trayendo mediante un objecto, pero no he podido traer los de _EnterpriseAttributes, o como puedo hacer para poder actualizar los atributos de un suscriptor? actualmente traigo los datos del suscriptor de la siguiente manera

> Google Translate English:
>
> I want to be able to retrieve and update the _EnterpriseAttributes
> fields of a subscriber, that is to say the user fields and their
> attributes, the _Subscribers fields I am bringing them through an
> object, but I have not been able to bring those of
> _EnterpriseAttributes, or how can I do to update the attributes of a subscriber? I currently bring the subscriber data as follows

```
 /* Crear el objeto del subscriptor */
  set @subscriber = CreateObject( "Subscriber" )
  SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "EmailAddress", @subKey )
  SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @subKey )

        /* Get all the subscriber attributes */
        SET @rr2 = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"ObjectType","Subscriber")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberID")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "DateUndeliverable")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "DateJoined")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "DateUnsubscribed")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Domain")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "EmailAddress")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "BounceCount")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberType")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Status")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Locale")
        
        

        /* Create a filter be the subscriber Id */
        SET @sfp2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp2,"Value",@subKey)
       
       
        
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"Filter",@sfp2)
        SET @sub_rowset = InvokeRetrieve(@rr2, @rrStatus, @rrRequestID)
        



output(concat("rrStatus: ", @rrStatus))
output(concat("<br>rrRequestID: ", @rrRequestID))


        IF ROWCOUNT(@sub_rowset) == 1 THEN
            SET @sub_row = ROW(@sub_rowset,1)
            SET @sk = FIELD(@sub_row,"SubscriberKey")
            SET @x = FIELD(@sub_row,"Status")
            SET @z = FIELD(@sub_row,"EmailAddress")


            OutputLine(CONCAT("SubscriberKey: ",V(@sk),"<br />"))
            OutputLine(CONCAT("Status: ",V(@x),"<br />"))
            OutputLine(CONCAT("email: ",V(@z),"<br />"))
            
               
        ENDIF  
          
          
          
    ]%%
```

pero cuando le agrego `AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Attributes")` me sale el siguiente error: 
`rrStatus: Error: The Request Property(s) Attributes do not match with the fields of Subscriber retrieve`

> Google Translate English:
>
> but when I add `AddObjectArrayItem (@ rr2, "Properties", "Attributes")`
> I get the following error:
>  `rrStatus: Error: The Request Property(s) Attributes do not match with the fields of Subscriber retrieve`

Comment: Bienvenidos a Salesforce Stack Exchange. La idioma de esto sitio es Inglés. ¿Puede traducir su puesto? (Lo siento por mi Español).

Comment: Agregué una versión solo de AMPscript en mi respuesta para usted según lo solicitado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Attributes part of the SOAP Object `Subscriber` is not retrievable, see below snippet from a Describe call to the object:

> Desafortunadamente, la parte de Atributos del objeto SOAP `Subscriber`
> no se puede recuperar, consulte el fragmento a continuación de una
> llamada de Describe al objeto:

```xml
<Properties>
  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
  <Name>Attributes</Name>
  <DataType>Attribute[]</DataType>
  <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
  <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
</Properties>
```

but oddly enough, if you filter by Subscriberkey and retrieve the property of `ID` from the Object, it will actually return them automatically (see below sample envelope):

> pero por extraño que parezca, si filtra por Subscriberkey y recupera
> la propiedad de `ID` del Objeto, en realidad los devolverá
> automáticamente (vea el sobre de muestra a continuación):

```xml
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
               <ClientID>1234567</ClientID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailTypePreference</Properties>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <!--This makes Profile Attributes show in the Results-->
            <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>example@email.com</Value>
            </Filter>
            <QueryAllAccounts>false</QueryAllAccounts>
         </RetrieveRequest>
```

which will return the Attributes as a nested rowset.

> que devolverá los atributos como un conjunto de filas anidado.

```xml
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>First Name</Name>
                    <Value>Gor</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Last Name</Name>
                    <Value>Tonington</Value>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Region</Name>
                    <Value />
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Country Code</Name>
                    <Value />
                </Attributes>
```

I personally would recommend doing this instead inside of WSProxy for faster processing as well as easier parsing and less code than AMPScript:

> Personalmente, recomendaría hacer esto en lugar de WSProxy para un
> procesamiento más rápido, así como un análisis más fácil y menos
> código que AMPScript:

```javascript
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  var subscriberkey = "example@email.com"

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var cols = ["CreatedDate","Client.ID","EmailAddress","SubscriberKey","Status","UnsubscribedDate","EmailTypePreference","ID"];
  var filter = {
      Property: "SubscriberKey",
      SimpleOperator: "equals",
      Value: subscriberkey
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("Subscriber", cols, filter);

</script>
```

Which will return:

> Que volverá:

```json
[
    {
        "SubscriberKey": "example@email.com",
        "EmailAddress": "example@email.com",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Name": "First Name",
                "Value": "Gor",
                "Compression": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "Last Name",
                "Value": "Tonington",
                "Compression": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "Region",
                "Value": "",
                "Compression": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "Country Code",
                "Value": "",
                "Compression": null
            }
        ],
        "ID": XXXXXXXXXX,
        "EmailTypePreference": "HTML"
    }
]
```

(I abbreviated it some to save space)

You can then get the values from this array by the following:

> (Lo abrí un poco para ahorrar espacio)
>
> Luego puede obtener los valores de esta matriz de la siguiente manera:

`var LastName = res.Attributes[0].Value;` which would output as: `Tonington`

> `var LastName = res.Attributes [0] .Value;` que se generaría como:
> `Tonington`

---

**EDIT**
If it absolutely positively needs to be in AMPScript, the below should show you how to collect it and parse it:

> **EDITAR** 
>  
>  Si es absolutamente necesario que esté en AMPScript, el siguiente debe mostrarle cómo recopilarlo y analizarlo:

```
%%[
 set @subKey = "example@email.com"

 /* Crear el objeto del subscriptor */
  set @subscriber = CreateObject( "Subscriber" )
  SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "EmailAddress", @subKey )
  SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @subKey )

        /* Get all the subscriber attributes */
        SET @rr2 = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"ObjectType","Subscriber")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "EmailAddress")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "ID")

        /* Create a filter be the subscriber Id */
        SET @sfp2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
        SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"SimpleOperator","equals")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp2,"Value",@subKey)      
        
        SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"Filter",@sfp2)
        SET @sub_rowset = InvokeRetrieve(@rr2, @rrStatus, @rrRequestID)
        
        output(concat("rrStatus: ", @rrStatus,"<br>"))
        output(concat("<br>rrRequestID: ", @rrRequestID,"<br>"))

        IF ROWCOUNT(@sub_rowset) == 1 THEN
            SET @sub_row = ROW(@sub_rowset,1)
            SET @sk = FIELD(@sub_row,"SubscriberKey")
            SET @x = FIELD(@sub_row,"Status")
            SET @z = FIELD(@sub_row,"EmailAddress")
            SET @a = FIELD(@sub_row,"Attributes")

            OutputLine(CONCAT("SubscriberKey: ",V(@sk),"<br />"))
            OutputLine(CONCAT("Status: ",V(@x),"<br />"))
            OutputLine(CONCAT("email: ",V(@z),"<br />"))
            OutputLine(CONCAT("Attributes: ",V(@a),"<br />"))

        SET @aRC = RowCount(@a)
            
        FOR @i=1 TO @aRC DO
           SET @aRow = ROW(@a,@i)
           SET @Name = FIELD(@aRow,"Name")
           SET @Value = FIELD(@aRow,"Value")
           OutputLine(CONCAT(@Name, ": ", @Value,"<br />"))
               
        NEXT @i
        ENDIF           
          
    ]%%
```

To gather it, you add in the ID property:

> Para recopilarlo, agregue la propiedad ID:

```
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "ID")
```

and to parse, you do it in a for loop like so:

> y para analizar, lo haces en un bucle for así:

```
        SET @a = FIELD(@sub_row,"Attributes")

        OutputLine(CONCAT("SubscriberKey: ",V(@sk),"<br />"))

        SET @aRC = RowCount(@a)
            
        FOR @i=1 TO @aRC DO
           SET @aRow = ROW(@a,@i)
           SET @Name = FIELD(@aRow,"Name")
           SET @Value = FIELD(@aRow,"Value")
           OutputLine(CONCAT(@Name, ": ", @Value,"<br />"))
               
        NEXT @i
```

Comment: perfect!! thank you very much. if i need to update each attribute independently i could save it in a different variable for each attribute? or there is some function to update these attributes independently thank you very much for the help

Comment: My recommendation would be to do something like `IF @Name == "FirstName" THEN SET @FirstName = @Value ENDIF` etc.. There are some more complex stuff that can be done to do this more dynamically/elegant, but that might be too much for what you need.

Comment: I will try to save the value of each attribute by means of the IF clause. Thank you very much for your help,  friend

Comment: can this also be done for ampscript?                                                                                
                                                                                                                                          
var LastName = res.Attributes[0].Value;

Comment: @JeferssonGomez You could do something like: `set @FirstName = Field(ROW(@aRC,1),"Value")` and then second one would be: `set @LastName = Field(ROW(@aRC,2),"Value")` but then you are also depending on the ordinal value of the columns. If someone changes the order, it will completely screw up your script.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To update the fields of _EnterpriseAttributes of a specific user by the subscriberkey, what function can I use?

Comment: @JeferssonGomez That might be better asked in a separate question - just to make sure this one stays focused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110138/discussion-between-jefersson-gomez-and-gortonington).